# How to transform CardView size and form on swipe up or click event?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-cardview, android-transitions

Is it possible on selected CardView swipe up or click (if swipe up not possible) to make CardView fill ~90% of the screen. And when clicked again, it shrinks down to its original form.
The important part is that it has to be on the same view as google maps are, so transition to other activity won't work for me and also I will be adding addition content to CardView when it will be enlarged.

I don't need exactly specifics on how to do it, but at least where to start.

Right now you can swipe left and right, and it will add shadow to object and enlarge current item.

Link to `.xml` and  transform class code: https://pastebin.com/0trtw1E1

Basically, i'm trying to implement https://github.com/mciekurs2/ViewPagerCards, but with a little bit of a twist.

[image]

Comment: @UserOne Yes both, its like a card, you can click or swipe up to read more about it

Comment: Right now you can swipe left and right, and it will add shadow to object and enlarge current item. What do you mean?

Comment: @РасулA-ев I updated question with example code and what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @UserOne But can I for example work around it? Make a second ViewPager and animate it the same way but dont show it until bottom one is clicked and animate transition between them?